# deleting folders with spaces in their names using xargs

Tags: command-line, find, xargs

Why can't xargs delete directories with spaces in their names, and how to fix that?

```
76 find . -type d |xargs  rm -rf
 77 rm -rf fire\ hydrant/
 78 rm -rf wine\ glass/
 79 rm -rf tennis\ racket/
 80 rm -rf traffic\ light/
 81 rm -rf parking\ meter/
 82 rm -rf teddy\ bear/
 83 rm -rf sports\ ball/
 84 rm -rf cell\ phone/
 85 rm -rf stop\ sign/
 86 rm -rf dining\ table/
 87 rm -rf potted\ plant/
```

Comment: Why not use `find`'s implemented `-delete` option?

Comment: I didn't know avout it

Comment: In that case: be sure to put it at the end! `find` will execute from left to right, so a `-delete` placed too early will result in too many files being deleted.

Comment: Also see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 24):

Fix it using `-print0` in `find` and `xargs -0` in `xargs` to tell both commands to use the NULL character as a separator instead of space:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Here's a nice explanation of why it breaks and how this fix works from [*The Linux Command Line* by William E. Shotts Jr](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php).

> **Dealing With Funny Filenames**
>
> Unix-like systems allow embedded spaces
>   (and even newlines!) in filenames. This causes problems for programs
>   like `xargs` that construct argument lists for other programs. An
>   embedded space will be treated as a delimiter, and the resulting
>   command will interpret each space-separated word as a separate
>   argument. To overcome this, find and xarg allow the optional use of a
>   null character as argument separator. A null character is defined in
>   ASCII as the character represented by the number zero (as opposed
>   to, for example, the space character, which is defined in ASCII as the
>   character represented by the number 32). The find command provides the
>   action -print0, which produces null-separated output, and the xargs
>   command has the --null option, which accepts null separated input.
>   Here’s an example:
>
> ```
> find ~ -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs --null ls -l
> ```
>
> Using this technique, we can ensure that all files, even those
>   containing embedded spaces in their names, are handled correctly.

(`-0` is the short version of the `--null` option)

Answer (score 17):

You don't need `xargs`, `find` itself can do it robustly with handling:

- any kind of possible filenames
- without triggering `ARG_MAX`

If the directories are empty, use `-delete` action:

```
find . -type d -delete
```

If not empty, use `rm -r` in the `-exec` action:

```
find . -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

---

If you insist on using `xargs`, for any directory names without newline in their names you can use newline as the delimiter of incoming arguments:

```
find . -type d | xargs -d $'\n' rm -r
```

Best way, get files NUL separated and deal with it with `-0` option of `xargs`:

```
find . -type d -name 'foo bar*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

**For all the `rm -r` used, add `-f` i.e. do `rm -rf` if needed.**

Comment: «without triggering `ARG_MAX`» → can this be solved using `xargs -n [something]` or is it a limitation of `xargs`? Besides, while *this specific case* can be done with `find`, it wouldn't work for e.g. a list of file names in a file or something else entirely. `xargs` is more general than `find`.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto `xargs` also handles `ARG_MAX`. It's just that as you're already using `find`, there's no need to spawn an extra process, and of course an anonymous pipe when `find` can do the needful alone.

Comment: Oooh!  -exec + is new (well, some time in the previous 20 years :-)  That's useful.

Comment: xargs is more efficient. -exec creates a subprocess for each file, while xargs baches them.

Comment: @paj28 No, you are referring to `-exec ... {} \;`, here I've used `-exec ... {} +` (note the `+` instead of `\;`) which takes as many files so as the `ARG_MAX` is not triggered.

Answer (score 2):

To specifically delete all subdirectories having spaces in their name, the simplest command would be :

```
find . -type d -name "* *" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This is the same approach as the one heemayl already suggested, the only difference being the `-name` filtering.